# Access xparse's \BooleanTrue via latex3 expl3

Tags: conditionals, expl3, latex3, xparse

I'm implementing a command with `xparse`'s boolean token processing

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\op}{s o t' t. t^ g}{
    % Here I need to check for
    %     (#3 || #4 || #5) && !(#3 && #4 && #5)
}
```

I'd like to avoid all the `\IfBooleanTF` combinations and instead to check via `\bool_if:nTF`. 
That is, of the boolean tokens passed to the function not all at the same time should be true or false. Testing with `\IfBooleanTF` for

(p ∨ q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(p ∧ q ∧ r)

is very tedious (a higher-order exclusive disjunction, XOR), especially given more such arguments.

I could assign boolean "variables" in expl3 based on xparse's tests, e.g.,

```
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
{\bool_set_true:N \l_first_arg_bool}
{\bool_set_false:N \l_first_arg_bool}
```

That's okay.
But is there a way to access the boolean flags set by `xparse` for the arguments directly?

Comment: Welcome do TeX-SX! Could you please try to explain your question in more detail and describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: Take a look into `xparse.sty`. The flags seem to exist only locally

Comment: Can't you just pass all variables to the underlying function and make the test there?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Good idea, I'll take a look.

Comment: @clemens: What do you mean by an underlying function?

Comment: @user89173 the LaTeX3 philiosophy is that every document command should have a code level equivalent: `\NewDocumentCommand{\op}{s o t' t. t^ g}{ \my_op:nnnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} }`

Comment: @clemens Your code shows exactly where the “lower level access” would be needed.

Comment: @egreg I agree. It works passing those boolean arguments to `\bool_if:nTF` but it isn't documented and hence may not be relied upon…

Comment: @clemens I already have a use case for something like `\bool_if_novalue:nTF` that otherwise is clumsy, requiring a new conditional.

Comment: @clemens: Would that indirection yield proper typing? That is, can I then apply `\bool_if:n` inside `\my_op:nnnnn` to `#1` etc.? Seems like @egreg confirms that.

Answer (score 6):

It is probably not such a good idea to rely on an implementation detail, but [`xparse` defines](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/5c808ba6074681c6b02882c1b0b23ae2d2eeb598/l3packages/xparse/xparse.dtx#L4261-L4262)

```
\cs_new_eq:NN \BooleanFalse \c_false_bool
\cs_new_eq:NN \BooleanTrue  \c_true_bool
```

which means that the booleans that are signalled by your arguments are just regular `expl3` booleans which can go directly into `\bool_if:nTF`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \op { s o t' t. t^ g }
{
  \bool_if:nTF { (#3 || #4 || #5) && !(#3 && #4 && #5) }
    { True }
    { False }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\op*[foo]'.^{bar} % False

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementing this XOR is quite easy:

```
\int_new:Nn \l_foo_bad_check_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\bad}{t' t. t^}
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_foo_bad_check_int
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 } { \int_incr:N \l_foo_bad_check_int }
  \IfBooleanTF { #2 } { \int_incr:N \l_foo_bad_check_int }
  \IfBooleanTF { #3 } { \int_incr:N \l_foo_bad_check_int }
  \int_compare:nTF { 0 < \l_foo_bad_check_int < 3 }
   { Good }
   { Bad }
 }
```

On the other hand, such a syntax would be confusing even for the macro creator, particularly with an argument specifier such as

```
s o t' t. t^ g
```

with *six* optional parts.